# UIPopoverViewController resized automatically

Tags: ios, resize, uipopovercontroller

I have a UIPopoverViewController with a Picker View, some text boxes, some labels and some segmented controls. I have the height of the view controller in the storyboard set to 640. When the application loads the popover it seems to be a fixed size and the controls are repositioned and some at the bottom are cut off.

How can I control the height of this popover view controller and what is causing it to resize? Links to any good references would be helpful.

Thanks!
Bob

Answer (score 0):

After you instantiate the popoverController, you call `- (void)setPopoverContentSize:(CGSize)size animated:(BOOL)animated;` to manually set the size of the popover.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I've tried this but it's still not working. The strange part is that if I call up the keyboard by entering one of the text boxes, the popover takes the correct size. Even after I dismiss the keyboard it stays the correct size, but you can only see the full popover if you bring up the keyboard.